# Response Content is not a valid JObject : Azure Functions with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

I am trying to execute this Azure Function via a Data Factory Pipeline and getting this Error "Response Content is not a valid JObject." for which I have added this into last section of my PowerShell Script ---> Body = "{ ""Response"":"""+$contents+"""}".

Now It is writing data to Data Lake but my pipeline is getting Failed with Error: ""Response Content is not a valid JObject." What I am doing wrong here ?

**PowerShell Script inside Azure Functions:**

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Connect to Azure Account


   $username = "xyz@abc.onmicrosoft.com"
   $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "**********" -AsPlainText -Force
   $cred = New-Object PSCredential($username,$pass)
   Connect-AzAccount -Credential $cred

# Input Variables

 $dataFactoryName="production-gen2"
 $resourceGroupName="DataLake-Gen2"

# get dataFactory triggers

$triggers=Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$datas=@()
foreach ($trigger in $triggers) {
    # get the trigger run history
    $today = Get-Date
    $yesterday = $today.AddDays(-1)
     $splat = @{ 
        ResourceGroupName       = $trigger.ResourceGroupName
        DataFactoryName         = $trigger.DataFactoryName
        TriggerName             = $trigger.Name
        TriggerRunStartedAfter  = $yesterday
        TriggerRunStartedBefore = $today
   }
    
   $historys =Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerRun @splat
   if($historys -ne $null){
     # create date
     foreach($history in $historys){
        $obj =[PsCustomObject]@{
            'TriggerRunTimestamp '     = $history.TriggerRunTimestamp
            'ResourceGroupName '   =$history.ResourceGroupName
            'DataFactoryName' =$history.DataFactoryName
            'TriggerName '  = $history.TriggerName
            'TriggerRunId'= $history.TriggerRunId
            'TriggerType'=$history.TriggerType
            'Status' =$history.Status

        }
        # add data to an array
        $datas += $obj
     }
   } 
   
  
 }

#  convert data to csv string

 $contents =(($datas | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join [Environment]::NewLine)

 # upload to Azure Data Lake Store Gen2

 #1. Create a sas token
 
  $accountName="dna2020gen2"
 
# $path = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"

 $YY = (Get-Date).year
 $MM = (Get-Date).month
 $DD = get-date –f dd
 
 $fileSystemName="dev"
 $filePath="Input/Triggers/YYYY=$YY/MM=$MM/DD=$DD/data.csv"
 $account = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName 'DataLake-Gen2' -Name $accountName
 $sas= New-AzStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob  -ResourceType Service,Container,Object `
      -Permission "racwdlup" -StartTime (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10) `
      -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2) -Context $account.Context
$baseUrl ="https://{0}.dfs.core.windows.net/{1}/{2}{3}" -f $accountName ,  $fileSystemName, $filePath, $sas

#2. Create file
$endpoint =$baseUrl +"&resource=file"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{"Content-Length" = 0} -UseBasicParsing

$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{guid}/resourcegroups?api-version=2016-09-01 -Method GET -Headers $authHeaders
$r.Headers["x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads"]

#3 append data
$endpoint =$baseUrl +"&action=append&position=0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{"Content-Length" = $contents.Length} -Body $contents -UseBasicParsing

#4 flush data
#$endpoint =$baseUrl + ("&action=flush&position={0}" -f $contents.Length)
#Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $endpoint -UseBasicParsing

#Check the result (get data)

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $baseUrl -UseBasicParsing


# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = "{ ""Response"":"""+$contents+"""}"
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trace the value you are assigning to Body. Most likely, this is not what the client expects: for example, not a well-formed Json. Depending on the `$contents` value, enclosing it in double quotes may not be enough. You may want to do something like this instead:

```
Body = @{ Response = $contents } | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: I never thought this way. Yes, I have tried your solution and it worked like a charm ! Thanks a ton